# Python:when I try to insert JSON file into Mongodb,if the json file is not valid its throwing an error.how to catch the error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Hi I am trying to insert json files into mongoDb.I have written the code and is working fine for me.

```html
import sys, json, pymongo,glob
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import json_util
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import template
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
from itertools import count


connection = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db = connection.Mysample
mycollection = db.Mynewsample
folder = 'C:/ESRILKA/Cloud Team/Tmobile/JSON To CSV  Files/JSON files/*.json'
jsonFiles = glob.glob(folder)
for file in jsonFiles:
    with open(file) as template:
                      
                try:                
                    template_dct=json.load(template)
                    result = db.Mynewsample.insert_one(template_dct)                    
                    print('Inserted post id %s ' % result.inserted_id)
                    
                except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError) as e:
                        print("Invalid json at")
                        pass
```

But now i would like to validate the json file before inserting.That is if the json is not valid it should show a message saying"parsing failed etc.."

Comment: ``try...except``?

Comment: `from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError`, and catch that on `template_dct=json.load(template)`

Comment: yes i would like to do a try and except

Comment: So you can. I'm not sure what the issue is? `json.load()` will fail on invalid JSON, before you get to inserting into your DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try, except. An example:

```
import json


def is_valid_json(json_string):
    try:
        json.loads(json_string)
    except:
        return False
    return True


# Return True
print(is_valid_json('{"name": "Jhon"}'))

# Return False
print(is_valid_json("{'name': 'Jhon'}"))
```

[**Demo**](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/c4a20bd3-732f-4b2f-972a-39f08f1aaf2c/?i=true)

Comment: Thanks!I am able to catch the exception.See edited snippet.But in my folder i have 2 json files where first one is valid and second is invalid.If i have to print the invalid json file name or identity...how can i do that.